# Call Rails helper in every view impliedly as first argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ajaxify

I have a Rail 4 application that uses the ajaxify_rails Gem. So only my content is loaded but not the full page. Now I have defined a helper method that I want to call in every view as first statement. My current approch is doing this explicit in every view, but this is much duplicated code. So I have many views all starting with

```
= rails_helper_method
...
```

Is there a way to to this impliedly on every view, or do I just have to call it over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is what [`layouts`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) are for. **Just call your helper method in your layout and since your views will use that layout so your helper method will also get called up**. In your layout file you can do:*

```
%body
  = rails_helper_method
  = yield
```

**Update:**

If you look at [`ajaxify_rails repo`](https://github.com/ncri/ajaxify_rails#extra-content), you can call its ajaxify_extra_content method in application_controller and then bind it to ajaxify event. You can do something like this:

```
def ajaxify_extra_content
  ... your extra html ...
end
```

and then bind it like this:

```
$(document).on 'ajaxify:content_inserted', ->
  $('#id_of_some_container_in_view').html $('#ajaxify_content #id_of_some_container_in_view').html()
```

you can also call your helpers directly like this:

```
def ajaxify_extra_content
  view_context.your_helper
end
```

PS I haven't tested it but this should work for you

Comment: In normal Rails applications this would work, but because of ajaxify_rails, the layout is not rendered when the user clicks on a link, so the helper method won't be called when rendering the new content.

Comment: Thanks, this would work, I also found an other solution that woorks too, the Gem `rails-ajax` can update multiple containers with different partials on one request, so you can achieve the same result.